Questions about Huygen's principle and diffraction
I'm going to ask about why wavelength and gap size affects diffraction. I'm aware this is a question that has been asked before here in various forms but reading through those answers hasn't been able to make everything make sense to me as of yet.
By Huygens' principle, you can consider a wave to be made out of infinitely many point sources that each radiate out their own secondary wavelets. I tried to make something quantitative out of this, but it has led to some confusions. Sorry in advance if I make mistakes with the math, I admittedly don't have too firm a grasp of what I'm doing as I'm trying to do stuff we haven't really covered in class.
Imagine a line from (-X, 0) to (X,0) in the XY plane acting as a source of a wave. Each point acts as its own source, so the displacement at a point (x,y) can be given as $\sum_i f(\sqrt {(x-x_i)^2+y^2}) $ where f is a function that gives the displacement at a distance from a source. So we're summing up the displacements from each point source at point $x_i$
Say we were modelling a snapshot of a sinusoidal wave at a certain time, so that the displacement at (x,y) is $\sum_i \sin(\sqrt {(x-x_i)^2+y^2}) $
As we increase the number of points to infinity, the displacement at (x,y) will go to $\int_{-X}^X \sin(\sqrt {(x-s)^2+y^2}) ds$
(I think? Am I handling the amplitudes of each secondary wave correctly by scaling it by ds?)
I threw this into a graphing calculator and got something that looks vaguely right, which I've attached below.

However, as I vary the gap size, it doesn't behave correctly. The diffraction doesn't appear to be greatest when the gap size is equal to the wavelength, as should be the case. When I have the gap size an odd number of wavelengths long, I see the wave spread out to the sides of the gap too. This makes sense to me given my understanding of Huygen's principle though.
When you have a gap of size $\lambda$, and you looked at a region ato the side of the gap, you would expect to see perfect destructive interference since for any point source, there is another point source along the gap half a wavelength down that will perfectly destructively interfere with it. And when you have a gap of $\frac{3} 2 \lambda$ you would expect that the one wavelength would destructively interfere with itself and the remaining half wavelength of point sources would result in a wave propagating along the axis of the gap. Like this:

I think there must be something wrong with my conceptual understanding of Huygen's principle, because I don't see why this wouldn't happen whenever you have a gap whose width is not an even number of wavelengths long.

your 3d pictures are hard to read. why not use th good pictures in wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction, or construct the interference at some points directly

There seem to be two issues here: 1) understanding basic scalar diffraction theory 2) understand it in terms of Huygens principle. I'd say you should first make sure you understand 1) before consider 2). Some of the expectations about scalar diffraction that are expressed in the post don't seem to be correct.

Diffraction of a finite plane water wave
Let a plane wave be finite. To get a better idea, you create one by periodically dipping a 1 m wide board into the water. Then you will notice that semi-circular waves are created at both ends - with decreasing intensity along the quarter circle. This has to do with the hemispherical dissipation of the wave's pressure. It is a 3D propagation that needs to be observed!  You can easily understand this for a point-fetal excitation of a wave.
Diffraction of a plane water wave at an edge
_ Side effect: If a plane wave hits an edge, the part of the wave that hits the obstacle is thrown back first - and interferes laterally into the continuing wave. This side effect should be included in a simulation.
_ Main scenario: After passing through the edge, the lateral end of the edge hits open water again, which is equivalent to the first scenario of the finite plane wave.
Diffraction of water waves at a slit (from two edges)
_ Prevention of the side effect: If you place a near-point source directly in front of the slit, you prevent the side effect described above, which describes the interference of the reflected wave with the main wave.
_ After the slit, exactly the same thing happens as at an edge, only once to the right and once to the left of the slit. There is no interference at all, only the interference due to dissipation, i.e. the weakening of the wave ends that diverge in a quadrant.
The width of the slit for water waves
_I f you look at a wide slit, you have the scenario of two edges far apart and a flat wave in between. The dissipation effects of the quarter circles occur at their ends.
_ If you make the slit very small, you are primarily dealing with the side effect of the interference of the reflected wave parts. This is definitely worthy of a simulation. Otherwise - take an almost point source in the simulation - and regardless of the amplitude of the wave and its frequency - there is no difference to a wider slit.
Consideration of the viscosity of the water
Of course, it is clear that you can assume any amplitude (introduction of energy into the wave) and frequency in the simulation, but in reality you have to take the viscosity of the water into account. Otherwise you will create vortices and splashes.

user385285: there must be something wrong with my conceptual understanding of Huygen's principle

In your pictures I think I can see that dissipation does not take place at the transition from the plane wave to the quarter-circle waves. Try to look at your simulation from the point of view of the law of conservation of energy.
